# QT GCC Error During Cross Compile Setup

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, beagleboneblack

I have been working this problem for more than a week. I installed the free version of QT off the QT site. I am trying to set up a cross compile environment for a Beaglebone Black ARM 8 platform. I have set up the compiler options using GNU ARM 6.3.0 GNU compiler -- The same compiler that is on my BBB. I successfully created the cross-compile environment and the Beaglebone device. The connect test worked correctly as well.

Here is the simple C++ application that I am trying to compile,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what my QT gcc compile options look like,

[image]

Here is my kit setup,

[image]

Here is my device setup,

[image]

When I build the default QT simple application I get these errors,

```
Running Windows Runtime device detection.
C:/Qt/5.11.0/winrt_armv7_msvc2015/bin/winrtrunner.exe --list-devices
Found 2 Windows Runtime devices.
Running "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E server "--pipe=\.\pipe{2e664e46-cacb-46ae-b680-ed9c235dc502}" --experimental" in C:\Users\Stephen\AppData\Local\Temp\QtCreator-WLEKuI\qtc-cmake-IDzcFnnJ.
Starting to parse CMake project, using: "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=C:/SysGCC/beaglebone-6.3.0/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe", "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=C:/SysGCC/beaglebone-6.3.0/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.exe", "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=", "-DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=".
The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
Check for working C compiler: C:/SysGCC/beaglebone-6.3.0/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/SysGCC/beaglebone-6.3.0/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
The C compiler

"C:/SysGCC/beaglebone-6.3.0/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.exe"
is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: C:/Users/Stephen/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-WLEKuI/qtc-cmake-IDzcFnnJ/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/PROGRA~2/Ninja/ninja.exe" "cmTC_c3136"
[1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_c3136.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_c3136.exe
FAILED: cmTC_c3136.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\SysGCC\beaglebone-6.3.0\bin\arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.exe    CMakeFiles/cmTC_c3136.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj  -o cmTC_c3136.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_c3136.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0   && cd ."
c:/sysgcc/beaglebone-6.3.0/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.exe: unrecognized option '--major-image-version'
c:/sysgcc/beaglebone-6.3.0/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.exe: use the --help option for usage information
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The build seems to issues a command to the GCC compiler suite to an executable called ld.exe.  I verified the path to ld.exe and it is indeed in the directory and handles my "ld --version" command.The error messages show ld.exe '--major-image-version' and fails. ld.exe does not support --major-image-version. Not sure why it is issuing this command to ld.exe.

I know these compilers work as I have manually compiled this program using g++ 6.3.0 compiler.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A make argument is wrong. Specifically:

```
    unrecognized option '--major-image-version'
```

You should remove the argument "--major-image-version" from your project's Makefile LFLAGS.

On windows there are 3 makefiles, Makefile, Makefile.debug and Makefile.release

Remove the argument from the one matching your current build config.

Comment: QT is not creating a Makefile.  When I create the bbbw device it forces me to define a cmake profile.  I have tried several iterations to be a qmake project but the build & Run/Devices part will only let me create a cmake profile.  Any ideas?

Comment: try to qmake from the compile menu... and search for the makefile. as "Shadow build" is enabled by default, the makefile won't be in your project directory. it should be at the same level as your project's folder, and its name should be something like build-_YourQtVersion_-_YourQtCompiler_.

Comment: I never got this to work.  My solution is to code in C++/QT in windows/x86, compile, debug a run.  Once I get it running in windows, I transfer the source to the Beaglebone and compile and run.  Works good enough to get the job done.  Getting the job done is how I get paid!

Comment: Was trying to find an answer to the same question.  Your solution sounds painful - compiling natively on the Beaglebone.